# Как закрепить задний фон?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Возможно, я не очень хорошо сформулировал вопрос, но суть вот в чём. На моём сайте в качестве заднего фона стоит изображение. И я мышкой могу его "взять"(см. фото).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть мышкой я могу перетащить данную картинку, но мне нужно, чтобы я не мог с ней взаимодействовать.

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: img draggable="false"

Comment: чтобы такого не происходило - фон нужно делать фоном (background), а не объектом-картинкой (img).

Comment: pointer-events: none